# Can I pay my "Good to Go" toll bill without a "Good to Go" pass and without having to have access to the letter they sent me?

Tags: usa, driving, payment, tolls, washington-state

I drove through some bridges and tunnels in Seattle, some of which had a toll fee levied by the [Good to Go toll collection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_to_Go_(toll_collection_system)).

Can I pay my "Good to Go" toll bill without a physical "Good to Go" pass  placed on my car's windshield and without having to have access to the physical letter they sent me by mail (which contains the statement number)?

Comment: https://mygoodtogo.com/EN/bill-payments/toll-bills/landing "Please contact us if you have lost your bill.".  So they must have some way to accept payment from people who don't have the paper statements and/or the numbers on them.  Like Jonathan says, they probably don't make this easy for privacy reasons - it isn't desirable for any random person who knows your license plate to be able to find out when your car crossed a bridge.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, good catch!

Comment: For next time, it'll be easier if you make an account before driving on the roads.  According to https://mygoodtogo.com/EN/learn/how-to-pay/accounts you can make an account without having to get a physical pass (though you pay a little less if you do get the pass).

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, agreed, I was ill-prepared. Annoying that each US state and even county/city are so different (different laws, toll collection systems, etc.)

Comment: It’s even worse in Europe where some countries want you buy a vignette to drive on their roads, even if for a few miles.

Comment: @JonathanReez https://www.autoeurope.com/travel-tips/vignette-stickers/: "vignettes are quite affordable and can be acquired at any border crossing into said required country." I prefer that system, because no mail (makes more sense when traveling) + announced ahead of time.  Would be better to have 1 EU-wide vignette though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [GoodToGo](https://mygoodtogo.com/EN/sign-up-landing):

> What if I already drove on a toll road or have unpaid toll bills?
> Don’t worry, it's not too late to save money. We'll lower any unpaid
> tolls and you'll pay the reduced toll rate as a part of the account
> set-up process.
>
> What you'll need to tell us to finish this step-by-step process:
>
> - Vehicle information – Make, model, color, year, and license plate number.
> - Payment information – A valid credit card, debit card, or checking account information (bank account number & routing number).

Its super annoying that you can't just pay by license plate but I guess they did it to avoid bots harvesting data on which car drove through the tunnel on which day.

Comment: Thanks for the information! If I sign up for a new account, will that allow me to pay my "Good to Go" toll bill without a "Good to Go" pass and without having to have access to the letter they sent me? My guess is that when I  drove through the first toll, they created an account for me, so unless I have the info to connect to this account which is likely in the physical letter they sent/will send me, then I can't pay bills for it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes it will work